# Use of unassigned variable error when I am trying to assign values to variables using IF statements

Tags: c#, winforms, unassigned-variable

I am writing a program in Windows Forms which I am trying to assign values to variables using IF statements depending on which radiobuttons in the form are clicked. I am getting an error "use of unassigned variable" on the lines below in bold. The issue is that `TotalWeeks` has apparently not been assigned, however I assigned it a value in the IF statement above that one. Can anyone suggest a possible fix or idea to try and sort out the issue?

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Assigning variables
    int WeeklyRate; //To assign integer values for "WeeklyRate" for future calculation use. If Radio button clicked it has value of radio button etc. 
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        WeeklyRate = 10;
    }
    else if (radioButton2.Checked)
    {
        WeeklyRate = 15;
    }
    else if (radioButton3.Checked)
    {
        WeeklyRate = 20;
    }

    int TotalWeeks;//assign values to total weeks based on number of months selected, to use in calculations for total cost.
    if (radioButton4.Checked)
    {
        TotalWeeks = 12;
    }
    else if (radioButton5.Checked)
    {
        TotalWeeks = 52;
    }
    else if (radioButton6.Checked)
    {
        TotalWeeks = 104;
    }

    int Payments;//assigning the amount of payments based on frequency radiobutton selected. 
    if (radioButton7.Checked)
    {
        **Payments = TotalWeeks;**
    }
    else if (radioButton8.Checked)
    {
        **Payments = TotalWeeks / 4;**
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: What happens to `WeeklyRate` when neither of `radioButton1`, `radioButton2`, `radioButton3` is checked? What happens to `TotalWeeks` when neither of `radioButton4`, `radioButton5`, `radioButton6` is checked? What happens to `Payments` when neither of `radioButton7`, `radioButton8` is checked?

Comment: Thanks i've taken that on board and added an error message, however it doesn't help my issue with the use of "TotalWeeks" variable in the assignment of value to the "Payments"  Variable near the bottom of my code example. Can you help please?

Comment: That was not a side note about an unrelated issue with your code. That was the reason why you are correctly getting this error message from the compiler. You cannot shut up the compiler by displaying a message to the user without fixing the problem with code.

Comment: Hi GSerg, thank you very much. I am new at this but I just needed pointing in the right direction. I like your style of guidance :). I learned that i need to assigned the variable some sort of null default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When neither of `radioButton4`, `radioButton5`, `radioButton6` is checked, then you can't for example divide it by 4.

You should use this when initializing variable

```
int TotalWeeks = 0;
```

(result: `Payments` will be 0 when radioButtons aren't checked)

---

or this when initializing

```
int? TotalWeeks = null;
```

and this when assigning the amount of payments

```
if (radioButton7.Checked && TotalWeeks is not null)
{
    Payments = TotalWeeks;
}
else if (radioButton8.Checked && TotalWeeks is not null)
{
    Payments = TotalWeeks / 4;
}
```

(result: Now `Payments` variable is unassigned, when radioButtons aren't checked)

Edit: Thanks [GSerg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11683/gserg), I forgot about `?` after `int` to make it nullable